# Operadores de pre y post incremento c++

Tags: c++

Quién me explica el comportamiento de esto, por favor:

```
unsigned int q = 0;
cout << q++ << " " << q++ << endl;
cout << q << " " << q++ << endl;
cout << q++ << " " << q << endl;
cout << ++(q += ++q) << " " << ++ ++q << endl;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que parte no entendes de ese codigo? lo probaste?

Comment: No te explicaré el comportamiento, pero sí que te diré que si ves código así, es síntoma de que algo se está haciendo muy, muy, muy mal.

Comment: Deberías estudiar C++ con algún buen libro. O preguntarle a algún tonto bien dispuesto, que para las expectativas de un vago quizás sea suficiente.

Comment: +1 _(Al comentario de asdasdasd)_, Me ha dado bastante risa responder esta pregunta, pero este comportamiento indefinido me ha dado cáncer de globo ocular.

Answer (score 6):

No hay mucho que explicar... a cada uno le va a dar un resultado diferente.

La primera línea puede ser `00`, `01`, `10`, ... y algo parecido con las siguentes y esto es así porque C++ se centró en el rendimiento y, en consecuencia, deja bastante margen de maniobra a los compiladores a la hora de optimizar determinados juegos de instrucciones.

Efectivamente en C++, `q++` es una instrucción con un *postincremento*, por lo que si hacemos esto:

```
int q=0;
std::cout << q++;
std::cout << q++;
```

Vemos que efectivamente se imprime la secuencia `01`... sin embargo, la instrucción `std::cout << q++ << q++;` arroja un resultado indeterminado ¿por qué?

Básicamente porque el estándar indica claramente que en un postincremento primero se evalúa la variable y después el incremento... pero no dice absolutamente nada acerca de cuándo se debe ejecutar ese incremento... bueno sí, dice una cosa y es que debe ejecutarse antes del siguiente *punto de secuencia*...

En este caso los puntos de secuencia se establecen al final de cada instrucción (el punto y coma), luego los postincrementos se pueden ejecutar en cualquier momento entre la evaluación de la variable y el final de la instrucción.

Por otro lado... no podía ser de otra forma, el orden en el que se evalúan las variables es indeterminado, por lo que la primera línea de tu código podría acabar convertida en uno de estos casos:

**Caso 1:** postincrementos al final

```
std::cout << q;
std::cout << q;
++q;
++q;
```

**Caso 2:** evaluación de izquierda a derecha

```
std::cout << q;
++q;
std::cout << q;
++q;
```

**Caso 3:** evaluación de derecha a izquierda

```
int temp = q;
++q;
std::cout << q;
std::cout << temp;
++q;
```

Y con el resto de instrucciones más de lo mismo... así que ya sabes, no hagas este tipo de cosas en el código porque el resultado será impredecible.

Algunas aclaraciones adicionales:

**versiones anteriores a C++11**

En estas versiones los puntos de secuencia se definen tal que:

> At certain specified points in the execution sequence called sequence points, all side effects of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations shall have taken place. (§1.9/7)

Que viene a decir lo siguiente:

> Un punto de secuencia es un punto determinado en la ejecución en el que los efectos secundarios de las evaluaciónes previas deben estar completos. Las evaluaciones posteriores a este punto no tendrán efectos sobre las evaluaciones previas.

Como puedes ver hace referencia a efectos secundarios... ¿Qué es esto?

Los efectos secundarios son cambios que se producen en el estado de la aplicación (es decir, variables que cambian su valor) y que pueden afectar al resultado de la ejecución. Como ejemplo valga la primera línea del código de la pregunta:

```
cout << q++ << " " << q++ << endl;
```

Aquí hay dos efectos secundarios que son los dos incrementos de `q`. Son efectos secundarios porque no está especificado en qué momento concreto se deben ejecutar. Únicamente sabemos que se son operaciones que se habrán ejecutado sí o sí al llegar al punto y coma que delimita la línea de código.

**¿Qué puntos de secuencia podemos encontrar?**

- Operadores lógicos:

  - `A && B`
  - `A || B`
- if ternario: `A ? B : C`
- operador coma: `A , B`.

  **No será aplicable** cuando la coma actúe como un mero **separador**, por ejemplo en las llamadas a funciones: `func(A,B)`
- En las llamadas a función, después de evaluar todos los argumentos de la llamada.

Por poner algunos ejemplos de comportamientos **no indefinidos**:

```
int a = 0;
bool b = a++ || a++; // a = 2
b = a++ || a++;      // a = 3 <--- la expresión sufre cortocircuito
b = a++ && a++;      // a = 5
a++, a++;            // a = 7
a++ ? a++ : a=0;     // a = 9
```

Comportamientos **indefinidos**:

```
int a=0;
int b = a++ + a++;
func(a++,a++);
b = (a++ + a++) + a++;
```

**C++11 en adelante**

En C++11 desaparece el concepto de *punto de secuencia*. Su ámbito se divide en tres elementos diferentes para identificar mejor cada comportamiento aunque el comportamiento es exactamente el mismo:

- secuenciado antes
- no secuenciado
- secuencia indeterminada

Answer (score 2):

Agregando poca cosa... Ahí te explico el comportamiento que obtuve de tu código.

El operador de incremento `++` tanto en C como en C++ actuan de la siguiente manera *(Asumo que ya lo sabes)*:

- Pre-incremento: Incrementa el valor de la variable antes de utilizarlo.
- Post-incremento: Incrementa el valor de la variable LUEGO de haber retornado su valor previamente.

Por lo que tenemos:

```
unsigned q = 0;
cout << q++ << endl;
cout << ++q << endl;
```

Imprimirá:

```
0
2
```

Al momento de imprimir el `q++`, el operador `++` se encarga de retornar el valor de q y luego incrementar su valor, por eso nunca se ve el 1 en pantalla, cuando llega el momento de hacer `++q`, primero se incrementa y luego muestra en pantalla el valor del 2.

Aplicado a tu código podría decirse que *(...)*:

- Imprime el valor de `q`, luego incrementa su valor *(Que ahora es 1)*, imprime nuevamente el valor de `q` y por último, incrementa su valor; en este ejemplo, `q` tiene el valor de 2 al final:

  ```
  cout << q++ << " " << q++ << endl;
  ```
- Imprime el valor de `q` *(Si seguimos la secuencia, es 2)*, luego imprime nuevamente su valor *(2)* y posteriormente incrementa la variable *(Para que su valor sea 3 ahora)*:

  ```
  cout << q << " " << q++ << endl;
  ```
- Imprime nuevamente el valor de `q` e incrementa para que su valor sea 4 y posteriormente imprime su valor:

  ```
  cout << q++ << " " << q << endl;
  ```
- Por último: Lo que haces aquí es *hermosamente horroroso (IMHO)*, primero pre-incrementas el valor de `q` para sumarlo y asignarlo a `q`, que luego es incrementado, dando lugar a: `++(4 += ++4)` que sería simplificado a: `++(5 += 5)` y por último `++(10)`, luego de imprimir este valor *(En mi caso 11)*, se ejecuta `++ ++q` que evalua `++ ++11 -> ++ 12 -> 13`:

  ```
  cout << ++(q += ++q) << " " << ++ ++q << endl;
  ```

Este ha sido el resultado que me ha arrojado el [ideone](https://ideone.com/6Z4bw2) y es como menciona [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135237/4499) en su respuesta, todo esto es totalmente dependiente de compilador el hecho de aplicar estas optimizaciones, incluso de plataforma.

Puedes probar con `printf` de `cstdio` y veras un resultado totalmente distinto.